# Sales prediction in Azure ML

Tags: azure, prediction, azure-machine-learning-service

I am very new to Azure Machine Learning things, one of our client use to sell some fresh products to business people. They have a 'suggested buy' system, a feature will suggest some quantities to buy based on customer's sales history.

After client came to know about Microsoft's Azure ML, they want to use that prediction system to suggest quantities to customers.

We have sales data with these columns,

- CustomerName
- ItemName
- OrderDate
- QuantityPurchased
- QuantitySold

We would like customers have suggested quantity should come from Azure ML using the Sales Data.

Can some one please suggest me how can I do this?

Thanks much in advance.

Comment: IMHO I don't think Azure ML is a good fit for this. You could just deal with this by executing a query on your database that gets the customer from your historic sales numbers and then find the average quantity.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the generic template for doing retail sales forecasting:

https://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/Collection/Retail-Forecasting-Template-1

Here is the experiment that is pretty good starting point for exactly this type of problem - https://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/Experiment/Regression-Demand-estimation-4