# Azure machine learning predict order for customer

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I have created a new experiment in Azure Machine Learning and added two datasets by manually uploading csv's.

- One is from a customer of which I'd like to predict which products he will order next.
- The second dataset has the same type of data, only then from all other customers as reference for learning.

I have `productid`, `amount`, and `orderdate` and `orderid` for grouping and putting it on a timeframe.
The customer (dataset one) is always several months behind with ordering the latest products. therefor I added the dataset two with all other customers as reference.

Also because the reference can tell which products are more popular (ordered more and by several customers) so perhaps I should add a customerid column to the dataset.

I know how to start and get the data in, and I do know that it is common to split the data for training, feed it to the train model with a `Ilearnerdotnet` type and give the output to the score model and evaluate the model.

[image: current experiment]
I do not know how to choose a classification type and how this can give an output for the next three months of order. I have read some tutorials, but I just need someone who can give me some pointers.

**edit** I have added the customerid to the dataset so that I have just one set now which I should split to focus on a specific customer.
**edit2** found these templates. will look into it https://stackoverflow.com/a/36552849/169714

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go over this http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/5/A/05AE6B94-E688-403E-90A5-6035DBE9EEC5/machine-learning-basics-infographic-with-algorithm-examples.pdf

If above infographic doesn't help, then you can try all of the learners by going over this experiment and use the one with best results - https://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/Experiment/Algo-Evaluater-Compare-Performance-of-Multiple-Algos-against-Your-Data-1

Comment: Thank you for the PDF. I know now that I need regression and that the bike rent sample seems to suit me. The subtitle at the algorithms make it a bit easier to understand.